# Прошу дать совет по структуре базы данных MySQL

Tags: mysql

Уважаемые знатоки!
Переделываю сайт по формированию документов. Создал три таблицы **‘score’, ‘act’, ‘document’** и сейчас понял, что ошибся в самом начале. В этих таблицах я планировал хранить шаблоны этих документов и непосредственно сами рабочие документы. У всех таблиц есть колонка **‘parent_id’**, и к определенному шаблону я вытаскиваю список документов соответствии с **‘parent_id’**.
Когда я дошел до формирование рабочих документов на основании шаблонов, до меня дошло что при добавлении в эти таблицы рабочих документов у меня будут повторятся **‘parent_id’** для шаблонов и **‘parent_id’** для рабочих документов, что приведет к неправильному выводу данных пользователю, просто все перепутается.

И вот сам вопрос. Как лучше сделать?

1. Продублировать таблицы, например **‘template_score’, ‘template_act’, ‘template_document’** и соответственно **‘work_score’, ‘work_act’, ‘work_document’**.
2. Или добавить в каждую таблицу еще один столбец, например типа **enum (‘template’,’ work’)**, и хранить все в одном месте?

В каждой таблице планируется от 5000 записей.
Очень прошу вас поделиться своим опытом и как бы вы решили сделать?
Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: *В этих таблицах я планировал хранить шаблоны этих документов и непосредственно сами рабочие документы.* Это - в общем ошибка. Шаблон и документ - это разные сущности. Соответственно они должны храниться в разных таблицах.

Comment: @akina, но по сути они полностью идентичны, между ними разницы нету. Вы считайте все ровно надо их разделить в разные таблицы?

Comment: По-моему, говоря "шаблон", Вы имеете в виду что-то совсем не то, о чём говорю я... Вероятно, Вы имеете в виду полузаполненную запись в таблице с некими дефолтными значениями в части полей? Тогда отдельная таблица и правда необязательна - просто блок записей-шаблонов находится в нижних "адресах" автоинкремента (скажем, полсотни штук с ID от 1 до 50), а документы имеют ID начиная, скажем, с тысячи... хотя я бы всё равно делал отдельную таблицу. Ну хотя бы потому, что обычному процессу шаблон, в отличие от сделанного по нему документа, должен быть доступен исключительно на SELECT.

Comment: @akina, да действительно, шаблоны хранят предзаполненные поля (например название услуги) и при создании рабочего документа, туда добавляется только значение суммы. Немного не понял эту фразу: "что обычному процессу шаблон, в отличие от сделанного по нему документа, должен быть доступен исключительно на SELECT"

Comment: Ну то есть прочитать шаблон и создать на его основе новую запись может любой пользователь, а вот изменить его - только админ (скажем, root). Иначе - открывает обычный оператор программу, загружает на редактирование запись документа, которая по ошибке или намеренно оказывается шаблоном, правит, сохраняет - и вот оно, счастье...

Comment: @akina, я понял, но на это у меня есть в таблице четкие разграничения по правам. Меня больше смущает скорость выборки из базы данных, если я добавлю в SELECT еще одно условие WHERE 'значение' = (template|work), я боюсь что это замедлит выборку. Но я с вами наверное соглашусь и скорее всего разнесу это все по разным таблицам. Спасибо вам за совет и комментарии.

Comment: *на это у меня есть в таблице четкие разграничения по правам.* В MySQL не существует row-based security... SELECT privilege granularity = column. А если что-то там обеспечивается клиентской логикой - так это ни о чём...